# Compiling Kernel on Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel, debian

Due to hardware issues I want to install a new Kernel following [this](http://linuxg.net/compile-kernel-3-9-on-debian-wheezy/) guide.
But I am a little confused with this line:

```
$ sudo time fakeroot make-kpkg -j4 --initrd kernel_image kernel_headers
```

where I have to set the number of cores my processor has.
I have an Intel `i7-720QM` which is a quad core. But I guess because of hyperthreading (at least I think my processor is hyperthreaded) I have to use the option `-j8` instead of `-j4`. is this okay?

Note: In the comments of the guide above, this question was also asked, and one answer wos to use `-j4` the other was to go with `-j8` so i am confused now.

kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-j4` argument to `make-kpkg` (which gets passed to the underlying `make`) only sets the number of parallel compilation processes during the kernel build (and has no influence on the produced kernel packages). And it does not matter that much (so `-j4` or `-j8` won't make a very big difference in term of build time).

I often pass only `-j3` to leave a core available to other processes (e.g. my web surfing or my email reading during the kernel compilation).

Also, some part of `make-kpkg` is intrinsically serial and cannot be parallelized (some `tar` running....)

And you could even remove the `-j4` (same as `-j1`): kernel build time will increase, but your machine will be more responsive during it

<sup>PS: you don't need both `sudo` and `fakeroot` if the parent directory (`..`) is user-writable. It will contain the produced `.deb` packages. BTW, you could edit your `/etc/kernel-package.conf`.</sup>